# Copy Raster changes max and min values of the newly created raster band in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, netcdf, visualisation

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.8 and I imported a NetCDF file. Please find the NetCDF file attached. I imported it with multiple dimensions and multiple variables using the "Add Multidimensional Raster Layer" tool from the Add Data Toolbox. After adding it as a raster layer using the "Multidimensional multivariate raster" option in the tool, I used the "Copy Raster" tool from the geoprocessing toolbox. I used all the default environments and checked "Process as Multidimensional" and "Build Multidimensional Transpose". It was able to successfully copy the raster but the final raster had the maximum and min values between 25 and 0 while the original raster had values between 25 and 10. The overall color representation was also different for pixels however when I checked randomly the pixel values for both original and copied raster, they were identical for similar locations.

How can I adjust the max and min values and colors? What should I change in the Copy Raster tool so it produces exactly the same output?

https://gofile.io/d/HKfmD2

Comment: Try running build statistics tool on your raster.

Comment: @Hornbydd Copy raster by default builds statistics as one of its environment